# Why is the value not being returned as it should be here?

Tags: scala, return

Why does this work?

```
object Foo extends App {
  def bar(s: String): String = {
    if (s.size == 0) "empty string"
    else if (s.size == 1) s + s
    else s.head + bar(s.tail)
  }

  println(bar(""))
  println(bar("s"))
  println(bar("soom"))
}

[info] Running example.Foo
empty string
ss
soomm
```

While this one doesn't.

```
object Foo extends App {
  def bar(s: String): String = {
    if (s.size == 0) "empty string"
    if (s.size == 1) s + s
    s.head + bar(s.tail)
  }

  println(bar(""))
  println(bar("s"))
  println(bar("soom"))
}

java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
```

Shouldn't the `return`s short-circuit the code and not go forward? I feel that there's a simple explanation to why the second code snippet is not working, but I can't seem to find out why.

Comment: It should ... But there is NO `return` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you're missing a `return` statement.  In Scala the value on the last line of a function is returned as the return value.

Now your first code segement works because if else statements are treated as one expression and thus you do have an expression as the last line to return.

In your second code snippet the first two ifs have no effect because there's no return statement.  They are evaluated then nothing happens.  Your empty string case will make it to the `s.head + bar(s.tail)` line and the fail because .head cannot find an element.

You can either use your first code snippet or change your second one to this..

```
object Foo extends App {
  def bar(s: String): String = {
    if (s.size == 0) return "empty string"
    if (s.size == 1) return s + s
    s.head + bar(s.tail)
  }

  println(bar(""))
  println(bar("s"))
  println(bar("soom"))
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: "In Scala the value on the last line of a function is returned as the return value." that's not true.

Comment: Note that you *should* structure your code as in first example, using return is discouraged in scala.

Comment: @pedrofurla What is the correct way to say this?  Isn't it the case that the value of an expression on the last line will be returned?

Comment: @pedrofurla Are you just trying to call out the distinction between the last line and the last line evaluated?

Comment: @evan058, exactly.